# Coupled pdes of the first order

Tags: pde, numerics, nonlinear-equations

May question is about possible approaches to solve the following system
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\nabla{n}&=&n\,\mathbf{E},\\
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}&=&1-n,
\end{array}
$$
in general with some boundary conditions (BC). In particular, I'm interested to solve it in the polar coordinates
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\partial_rn&=&nE_r,\\
\partial_{\varphi}n&=&rnE_{\varphi},\\
\partial_r{(rE_r)}+\partial_{\varphi}{(E_{\varphi})}&=&r(1-n),
\end{array}
$$
plus some BC.

Any suggestions?

**Update 1**

According to request of @nicoguarolet let's say that boundary conditions are as follows
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\left.n(r,\varphi)\right|_{r=r_L}=n_0\approx1,~
\left.E_{\varphi}\equiv E_r(r,\varphi)\right|_{r=r_L}=E_0\approx0,\\
\left.\partial_rE(r,\varphi)\right|_{r=r_R}=0,\\
\end{array}
$$
where $[r,\,\varphi]\in[r_L,\,r_R]\times[\varphi_L,\,\varphi_R].$ Hope, that I haven't missed somewhat.

Comment: Boundary conditions are important for the solution of PDE, can you add them?

Comment: @nicoguaro Original post was updated.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a valid system of PDEs. In particular, the equation
$$
  \nabla n = n\mathbf E
$$
implies that you can find a function $n$ whose gradient equals a given vector field (n\mathbf E), but that's not possible for arbitrary vector fields. To see this, apply the curl to both sides:
$$
  \nabla \times \nabla u = \nabla\times (n\mathbf E)
$$
and remember that $\nabla \times \nabla = 0$. In other words, the equation will only have a solution if 
$$
  \nabla\times (n\mathbf E) = 0,
$$
but your other equation does not guarantee that that is the case.